# Overloading setw( )?

Tags: c++, overloading, setw

I would like a setw to take two parameters and return the largest. 
Is this possible?  How do I go about doing this? Not looking for code just some direction would be fine as I couldn't find a clear answer on-the-line.

Comment: You cannot overload it directly since it resides in namespace std (and adding custom overloads there is forbidden generally). I think it's possible to use some name lookup tricks to overload it in another namespace; but I don't quite see the advantage over Remy Lebeau's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can *overload* it, but you can certainly define your own type with a different name and then define `<<` and `>>` operators for it.  For example:

```
struct setw_largest
{
    int _value;
    setw_largest(int value1, int value2) : _value(std::max(value1, value2)) {}
};

template<class _Elem, class _Traits, class _Arg>
inline basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Istr, const setw_largest& _Manip)
{
    _Istr.width(_Manip._value);
    return _Istr;
}

template<class _Elem, class _Traits, class _Arg>
inline basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr, const setw_largest& _Manip)
{
    _Ostr.width(_Manip._value);
    return _Ostr;
}
```

```
std::cin >> setw_largest(1, 2) >> ...;
std::cout << setw_largest(1, 2) << ...;
```

Comment: The STL consists of mostly header files and inline implementations, so you can simply look at the `setw()` implementation to see what it actually does.

Comment: Underscore + capital letter = reserved identifier, [global.names]. This is intended in an StdLib implementation, but your own extensions shouldn't use them.

Comment: I will tackle this and give you feedback later. Thanks for the help.